# Where to fetchRecords in React - componentDidMount or onComponentDidUpdate or else where?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am attempting to get some records, from my redux store in a component. However, I am only trying to fetch records that belong to the currently logged-in user, which I get access to through my mapStateToProps function. -- ie, I am calling `fetchRuns(userId)`

I can't seem to figure out how or where to make this call. If I make the call in `componentDidMount`, userId is still null at this point. If I make the call in `componentDidUpdate`, I get an infinite loop, because my component updates when it returns. From my research, it sounds like I might need to keep track of another piece of state in `componentDidUpdate` that lets me know if I should make the call... I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

My code

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchRuns } from "../actions";
import RunCell from "./RunCell";

class Runs extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // TODO: BUG - go to run , refresh, hit cancel, all other runs are missing
    this.props.fetchRuns(this.props.userId);
  }

  renderRuns() {
    //Show runs in reverse chronological order
    const sortedRuns = this.props.runs.sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(b.runDate) - new Date(a.runDate)
    );

    return sortedRuns.map((run) => {
      return <RunCell {...run} key={run.id} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.runs) {
      return (
        <div className="ui container">
          <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
            <h3>Your Training Log</h3>
            <div className="right menu">
              <Link className="ui button right" to="/runs/add">
                Add Run
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="ui">{this.renderRuns()}</div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <div>Loading runs...</div>;
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { runs: Object.values(state.runs), userId: state.auth.userId };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchRuns })(Runs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the solution, you just need to compare the new `userId` prop with the old one to prevent the infinite loop:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchRuns } from "../actions";
import RunCell from "./RunCell";

class Runs extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.userId !== this.props.userId){ // <=== In order to prevent infinite loop add this comparison
       this.props.fetchRuns(this.props.userId);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.userId){ // <=== fetch your data inside this methode
      this.props.fetchRuns(this.props.userId);
   }
  }

  renderRuns() {
    //Show runs in reverse chronological order
    const sortedRuns = this.props.runs.sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(b.runDate) - new Date(a.runDate)
    );

    return sortedRuns.map((run) => {
      return <RunCell {...run} key={run.id} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.runs) {
      return (
        <div className="ui container">
          <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
            <h3>Your Training Log</h3>
            <div className="right menu">
              <Link className="ui button right" to="/runs/add">
                Add Run
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="ui">{this.renderRuns()}</div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <div>Loading runs...</div>;
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { runs: Object.values(state.runs), userId: state.auth.userId };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchRuns: (userId) => dispatch(fetchRuns(userId))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Runs);
```

Comment: Thanks -- I tried this earlier, but it's still not working fully as expected. With this solution, if I navigate to a detail page (a specific run), refresh (and in effect clear the runs out of my store) then cancel back to the ```Runs``` component page, the only "run" in my store is the one that I was on the details page for, all the other runs were cleared out on the refresh. But ```prevProps.userId !== this.props.userId``` is false so the ```fetchRuns``` doesn't happen.

Comment: What's the problem with this solution?

Comment: I think the solution is simple, we need to call the fetchRuns inside componentDidMount, your runs are empty because the new userId prop is similar to the old userId prop so the expression is false and we stop fetching our runs. I updated my answer.